# How to make a slide when the screen is zoomed out?

Tags: javascript, css

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

@media(max-width:768px) {
  .slideshow-container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .mySlides {
    display: none;
  }
  .prev,
  .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  }
  .next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  }
  .prev:hover,
  .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  }
  .dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  }
  .active,
  .dot:hover {
    background-color: #717171;
  }
  .fade {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {
      opacity: .4
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
  @keyframes fade {
    from {
      opacity: .4
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img class="main-description-img1 " src="images/main-colin.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    < <img class="main-description-img2" src="images/main-marching.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img class="main-description-img3" src="images/main-president.png" alt="">
    <a href="#">

  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    < <img class="main-description-img2" src="images/main-working.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
</div>
```

Hello.  How can i bind Javascript code to a media query in CSS so that it works only when the screen reaches a given width. At the beginning, all the blocks are arranged in a row. after shrinking the screen to 768px, I want the blocks to turn into a slide. how it can be implemented. I tried to add if (windows.innerWidth <= 768) {} to the code, so when this size is reached, the slides disappear altogether. Without a copper request in css and adding conditions to JS, everything works and shows as a slide.

Comment: You must put your if statement inside  an event listener with the "scroll" event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a media query like solution for javascript you have to listen for the `resize` event with an event listener and call the slide function `showSlides()` in it. In the slide function you have to wrap the code in the if statement that asks for `window.innerWidth`. Additionally you have to define an else block for showing the images again.

```
function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  
  if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
    ... //your original code of that function except the first two vars
  }
  else {
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "inline-block";
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    showSlides(slideIndex);
});
```

**Working example** (i changed `display: block` to `inline-block` for aligning the images in a row):

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  
  if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
      slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "inline-block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  }
  else {
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "inline-block";
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    showSlides(slideIndex);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

@media(max-width:768px) {
  .slideshow-container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .mySlides {
    display: none;
  }
  .prev,
  .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  }
  .next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  }
  .prev:hover,
  .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  }
  .dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  }
  .active,
  .dot:hover {
    background-color: #717171;
  }
  .fade {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {
      opacity: .4
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
  @keyframes fade {
    from {
      opacity: .4
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img class="main-description-img1 " src="https://loremflickr.com/160/120?random=1" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img class="main-description-img2" src="https://loremflickr.com/160/120?random=2" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img class="main-description-img3" src="https://loremflickr.com/160/120?random=3" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img class="main-description-img2" src="https://loremflickr.com/160/120?random=4" alt="">
  </div>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: what part of slide code i need to put in listener? i can't understand/ can you explain please?

Comment: For answering this it would be very helpful to have some html in you example. Please add one.

Comment: Yes it working, like i want. Yhank you very much. Can you explain me please, why we put if (window.innerWidth <= 768)  after two vars in function showSlides() exactly, and listener we put at the end of function? the fact is that I just started to study frontend development and have not yet studied javascript, but I made a layout and decided to add some functionality myself, so I started looking for answers on the Internet.

Comment: The vars have to be before the ```if``` since they are also used in the ```else```...